# How should i handle and fix the exception when the Interval of a timer is -1000?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the original this project the maximum speed was set to 900.
I wanted to make the maximum speed 2000.

This is the code:

```
[Editor(typeof(RangeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [MinMax(1, 2000)]
    [Category("Behavior")]
    public int MarqueeSpeed
    {
        get { return 1000 - tmrRefresh.Interval; }
        set
        {
            if ((1000 - tmrRefresh.Interval) != value)
            {
                if (1000 - value < 1)
                {
                    value = 2000;
                }
                if (1000 - value > 2000)
                {
                    value = 1;
                }
                tmrRefresh.Interval = 1000 - value;

                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
tmrRefresh.Interval = 1000 - value;
```

I know that if set the speed to 2000 so 1000 - 2000 = -1000
My question in this code what should be the way to handle this line or logic ? What should i change in the line so i will be able to change the maximum speed to 2000 or to 20000 ?

Comment: If you can't explain what result you want it is very hard to suggest any solution. So far it is clear that your code should fail the way you described, but there is no explanation what the code tries to achieve or what you expect to see in case that fails now.

Comment: Alexei the code is part of a project i took from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24587/Easy-to-Use-Marquee-Control-for-Windows-Form-with the code is user control that make marquee effect. I downloaded the source and saw that it was limit to maximum speed to 900. The speed the text is moving. So i wanted to change it i changed in all places to 2000 where it was 900. The other places were just static  global variables. The problem is in the part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code has non-linear speed. 600 is not 4 times as fast as 150, it is closer to only twice as fast.  And 999 is twice as fast as 998, except that timer precision is going to get in the way.  The logic gets infinitely fast as the "speed" gets close to 1000, there's no point at all in speeds above 1000.  And the reality is that speeds over about 984 will have no effect.

It's not a very good design at all.  Better would be to leave the interval constant, at the display's frame rate (or however fast the rendering system can adjust, if that is slower), and change the step size.  You might also need to maintain fractional position somewhere.  But that will make everything linear.

Comment: Ben but if i want to make it more faster ? The text inside is moving very slow. 900 is very slow. Any easy way to make the text to move faster ?

Comment: @user3482138: You can set it to about 970 for 30 FPS.  Higher than that won't make anything better, and higher than 1000 will be an error.  To go faster than what 970 gives, make the movements bigger, instead of more often.